# Delayed dispatcher invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, wpf

I knocked this up quickly to allow delayed `Invoke` on the dispatcher. Along with canceling the existing invocation and replacing with a new one, this allows throttling an action.

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer> timers = new Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer>();
    private static object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation, 
        Action action, TimeSpan delay, DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            DispatcherTimer timer = null;
            if (timers.TryGetValue(namedInvocation, out timer))
            {
                timer.Stop();
                timer.IsEnabled = false;
                timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
            }
            timer = new DispatcherTimer(priority,dispatcher)
            {
                Interval = delay
            };
            timer.Tick += (s, e)
                =>
                {
                    action();
                };
            timers.Add(namedInvocation, timer);
            timer.IsEnabled = true;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of improvements are you looking for? Do you think there's something wrong with your code? Also, do you really want to always invoke the actions repeatedly (that's what `DispatcherTimer` does) and have no direct way of truly canceling the invocation (without replacement)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an expert on multithreading at all, but I've attempted refactoring your code a bit.
First of all, to code defensively, I suggest adding the `readonly` modifier to your lock object. It's not required but will prevent accidental assignments:

```
private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();
```

I'm against incurring the complexity of an `out` argument: let's just check if the timer exists. We can stop it and remove it if it does; setting `DispatcherTimer.IsEnabled` isn't necessary because `DispatcherTimer.Stop()` [sets it to false anyway](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3163314/1106367):

```
if (timers.ContainsKey(namedInvocation))
{
    timers[namedInvocation].Stop();
    timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
}
```

We can get rid of the object initializer because `DispatcherTimer` has the perfect constructor for us anyway; this has the added benefit of inlining the lambda:

```
var timer = new DispatcherTimer(delay, priority, (s, e) => action(), dispatcher);
timer.Start();
timers.Add(namedInvocation, timer);
```

Again, remember we don't need to set `IsEnabled` because `DispatcherTimer.Start()` sets it to true for us (alternatively, you can leave it in place but remove the call to `Start()`. But the method call seems more intuitive to me; setting a property doesn't make it obvious that the timer has been started).

You may have noticed I used `var` wherever it seemed appropriate; it's just as type safe as using the actual type but takes up less space, both on the page in in my brain.

That leaves us with the following end result:

```
public static class DispatcherExtensions
{
    private static Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer> timers = 
        new Dictionary<string, DispatcherTimer>();
    private static readonly object syncRoot = new object();

    public static void DelayInvoke(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation,
        Action action, TimeSpan delay, 
        DispatcherPriority priority = DispatcherPriority.Normal)
    {
        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            if (timers.ContainsKey(namedInvocation))
            {
                timers[namedInvocation].Stop();
                timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
            }
            var timer = new DispatcherTimer(delay, priority, (s,e) => action(), dispatcher);
            timer.Start();
            timers.Add(namedInvocation, timer);
        }
    }
}
```

In case I introduced a bug or if you have improvements, let me know in the comments.

---

## Edit: supporting cancellation

*(@svick's suggestion)*

To provide the possibility of cancelling your timers, you would factor out the timer removing logic (I inverted the condition to reduce nesting...) into a new method that is called at the beginning of `DelayInvoke`.

```
private static void RemoveTimer(string namedInvocation)
{
    if (!timers.ContainsKey(namedInvocation)) return;
    timers[namedInvocation].Stop();
    timers.Remove(namedInvocation);
}
```

Then, you'd create another extension method (first parameter is useless, but calling the method via the Dispatcher is consistent and convenient, so I left it there). Something like this:

```
public static void CancelNamedInvocation(this Dispatcher dispatcher, string namedInvocation)
{
    lock(syncRoot)
    {
        RemoveTimer(namedInvocation);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I'd add to codesparkle's answer is that I find it better to move the action to the end, so that when you call the method, an anonymous method doesn't come before other parameters.

So instead of this:

```
MyDispatcher.DelayInvoke("SomeKey", () => {
     // ..
     // ..
     // ..
}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
```

You have this, which I think is more pleasant on the eye:

```
MyDispatcher.DelayInvoke("SomeKey", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), DispatcherPriority.Normal, () => {
     // ..
     // ..
     // ..
});
```

Although the downside is that the priority can no longer be a defaulted parameter.

Comment: You should post this as a comment to the answer, because it's not an answer in itself. But do you think it's wise to trade a feature for looks?

Comment: You can't post code in comments, and I felt it was a visual thing. Also, isn't this valid as an answer to a call for refactoring? I don't see it as a trade - what feature is being traded in? Also, it's not just looks. If that anonymous method gets long enough, anyone reading that code could miss that there are further parameters at the end. It's for transparency more than anything.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience there is rarely a need for delayed invokes on the dispatcher, what problem are you solving?

If you do something in a constructor that you want deferred until loaded there is already an overload for that:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Loaded, new Action(...));
```

For delayed invokes why not use:

```
public static async Task InvokeAsync(
    this Dispatcher dispatcher,
    TimeSpan delay,
    Action action)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(action).Task.ConfigureAwait(false);;
}
```

I would probably not have this as an extension method as it doesn't mean any real reuse of code.

For cancellation you can use this:

```
public static async Task InvokeAsync(
    this Dispatcher dispatcher,
    TimeSpan delay,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    Action action)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    await dispatcher.InvokeAsync(action, DispatcherPriority.Normal, cancellationToken)
                    .Task.ConfigureAwait(false);;
}
```

Passing in cancellation token is more consistent with how it is done in the framework.

With this design there is no risk for deadlocks and leaks.

I omitted the overload permutations with `DispatcherPriority`.